# Does Specflow's CompareToSet() need an Assert?

Tags: specflow, xunit, xunit.net

I'm using Specflow with xUnit, should I have an Assert with `void Table.CompareToSet()` (in the TechTalk.SpecFlow.Assist helpers)

Or it throwing an exception enough? If it throws any sort of exception it should fail (which it does fail ok), but I'm unsure whether I should be stricter by explicitly having an Assert?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having an exception is enough.

Don't forget, SpecFlow doesn't actually run your tests. It delegates that to NUnit/xUnit/MsTest. So if your code would fail the test in one of those it should also fail in SpecFlow.

*BTW, If you write your test first before you write your functional code then of course your test will fail, and that process checks that your fail will work, so you would see for yourself if this is sufficient.* ;-)

Comment: Thanks, that's the trouble I'm not sure if xUnit should also require an "explicit fail" as such. The tests fail ok if the implementation fails, the tests were written first (  Mostly :-) I'm learning specflow so I had a few gotchas ). But I think you've answered my question if the unit testing framework fails on an exception, than that is enough no more is needed?

Comment: Correct. SpecFlow lets the exception out so its up to the unit test framework.